# Block/hide partition for Windows

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, windows-8.1, linux-mint

I have a notebook w/ Win8.1 installed, and Linux alongside it in it's own partition.(duh)
The thing is, I don't want the Windows system to be able to put crap on the Linux partition. I'd like to set the Linux partition as read-only for Windows so Windows can't put stuff on it, but that it is still readable. Linux on the other hand, should be able to access all the partitions. Is this possible?

It would be great if it is, because Windows start polluting this partition as soon as I create it...
The best would be if I (easily)could set and unset the read-only option for this partition, so it is possible to access the partition quickly if necessary.

Unfortunately, just simply checking the read-box and unchecking all the other boxes in proprties->security->SYSTEM  of the partition doesn't do the trick, it seems.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: `Windows start polluting this partition as soon as I create it` - What does that mean? How is Windows "polluting" this partition?

Comment: Use a Linux partition format type that Windows doesn't recognize.

Answer (score 0):

you could always encrypt the entire linux drive (that is an option when you install recent versions of ubuntu at least), that way windows have no way to get to it, unless you choose to open it with a passphrase.

Comment: Ah thanks, thats great but is it also possible with Mint 16? I didn't pay attention to that at the time I installed it.

Comment: according to Fazer87 at the at the other answer, yes you can. but have to start from scratch.. so maybe that does not help you much?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the full disk encryption when you install the Mint OS.

I see from a comment you made on another post that you are running Mint 16 and asked if encryption was available.  According to [This Forum Page](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=136914) on the Mint Forums - Yes, it should be.  This forum says it was in version 15 and there is nothing in the release notes to say it was dropped in 16 - it will require a format of the drive though.